# How to map a model with reference to a list of another model in EntityFramework Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a project in which I am using EntityFramework Code First to manage the database. 
The models I'm using for this are as follows:

```
[Table("Data")]
public class Data
{
    [Key, Column("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("Code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Column("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual List<DataAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
[Table("DataAttribute")]
public class DataAttribute
{
    [Key, Column("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("IdData"), ForeignKey("Data")]
    public int IdData { get; set; }

    [Column("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Data Data { get; set; }
}
```

The issue I'm having with this is when I try to edit a Data object (along with its related DataAttribute values). I haven't gotten it to map correctly when submitting a form with both the Data elements and the DataAttribute elements. I give an example of .cshtml file.

```
@model MVCTestApp.Models.Data
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#new-row').click(function () {
                $('table tbody').append(
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td><input class="name" type="text" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input class="description" type="text" /></td>' +
                    '<td><a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a></td>' +
                    '</tr>'
                );
                $('.delete').click(function () {
                    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Data", FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.Id)
Name:
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Name)
    <br />
Description:
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Description)
    <br />
Code:
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Code)
    <br />
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Description
                </th>
                <th>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a id="new-row" href="#">New Row</a>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                </td>
            </tr>
            @if (Model != null) {
                foreach (var item in Model.Attributes) {
                    <tr>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(b => item.Id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(b => item.IdData)
                        <td class="name">@Html.TextBoxFor(b => item.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td class="description">@Html.TextBoxFor(b => item.Description)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

The question is this.

**How can I make EntityFramework recognize the list of DataAttributes on the Controller when posting?**

Here's the code I'm using right now.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Edit(Data model)
    {
        if (model != null) {

            db.Data.Add(model); //model has the model.Attributes list set as null
            db.SaveChanges();

            return View("Index", db.Data.OrderBy(a => a.Id).ToList());
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you need to ensure serialization of the list when you send it back to the controller. You could also try setting up a specific ViewModel that is returned that contains the list.

Comment: How would I serialize it?, by making it a json object or something like that and then passing it to the controller?

Comment: That could easily work, What I would do is add an argument to the ActionResult and set it to string and use the built in json parser to get the values and set the models attributes. you could use JSON on the client to serialize the object to be sent back.

Comment: I've been using json for this actually, but I'm having a lot of problems when actually saving the model to the db. I'm gonna go ahead and try the ViewModel approach. Thanks.

Comment: It makes things a little easier to maintain in my opinion.

Comment: I still haven't gotten the list to actually appear on the Controller, it always appears as null.

Comment: Ok so I would like to suggest you use something to help you with your ui. Take a look at knockout.js to handle lists and mapping them to models. Specifically take a look at the mapping plugin as it will allow you to pass your models directly into the framwork and then all of your model updates will be setup for you. Just a thought.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't end up using knockout.js, I changed a few things and posted an answer myself, thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I did the following: changed the foreach on the view to a for and used Attributes[i] instead so that it would use that to create the inputs (this is what makes the Controller actually receive the values) and I also changed the way the new rows are being created so that they would also use the same naming conventions and be passed unto the controller.

Here is the new view:

```
@model MVCTestApp.Models.Data
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#new-row').click(function () {
                var counter = $("#counter").val();
                counter++;
                $('table tbody').append(
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td><input id="Attributes_' + counter + '__Name" ' +
                    'name="Attributes[' + counter + '].Name" type="text" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input id="Attributes_' + counter + '__Description" ' +
                    'name="Attributes[' + counter + '].Description" type="text" /></td>' +
                    '<td><a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a></td>' +
                    '</tr>'
                );
                $('.delete').click(function () {
                    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                });
                $("#counter").val(counter);
            });
        });
    </script>
}
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Data", FormMethod.Post)) {
    var counter = 0;
    @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.Id)
Name:
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Name)
    <br />
Description:
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Description)
    <br />
Code:
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Code)
    <br />
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Description
                </th>
                <th>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a id="new-row" href="#">New Row</a>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                </td>
            </tr>
            @if (Model != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.Attributes.Count; i++) {
                    <tr>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.Attributes[i].Id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.Attributes[i].IdData)
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Attributes[i].Name)</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Attributes[i].Description)</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    counter = i;
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    @Html.Hidden("counter", counter.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand a couple of things. 
The first question is, why code first? You give us no reasons why not build the sql model and import with EF tools.
Then, you need to understand how ModelBinder mechanism works. You send an http post request with parameters, each one with a name and want to bind it to a Model class. ModelBinder tries to find that names in the Model class and that will never happen if you have tons of parameters with the same name. Also that kind of properties are called Navigation Properties and they should be loaded by EF or in a separated form.

For example, you're trying with ONE form to build a Data object with many DataAttributes. Why not create the Data object first and then , in another view, add the DataAttibutes? 
Thats whats the MVC is all about. Different Models -> Different Controllers -> Different Views.

If you don't separate responsibilities you're gonna have many more troubles ahead.

Comment: We are using code first because we are gonna be making a lot of changes to the DB and recreating the edmx file and updating it to the server would've taken way too long for it to be useful. I'm also doing the Data and DataAttributes on the same page because DataAttributes only exist to be modified inside of the Data, they are a part of it and it makes little sense (to me) to make another controller, view and everything just to edit them. I'm currently trying to create them correctly so that they are passed back into the Controller and I think I've found out how, will be posting if it's correct

Comment: Your solution isnt very good. You're creating a new model that makes no sense. There is no guarantee that in a DataEdit object the DataAttributes belong to the Data. Yes, you can make shure, but users can force hacking. You're just adding a new model that does not exist.
You should just rethought how MVC works and what it represents and how to struct your app. That is a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: Will think this through a bit more, the ViewModel should not be necessary, you're right, but the functionality does make sense from a user's point of view.

Comment: Got rid of the ViewModel, and it works, will update my answer.

Comment: I still think models should be separated but if you really want to do it yeah, that's a solution.
I think you can have troubles with that Delete depending on how you'll use it but it seems nice

Comment: Oh, that's just a fast demo I created, the delete functionality is not there still.

Comment: Yes i know :P i'm saying that you can have trouble when it is depending on how you're going to do it. But that is a hole other issue. Good luck with that